# Искренний пафос

Tags: семантика

На форуме "Грамоты" столкнулся с определением "искренний пафосный". 
Контекст того разговора опускаю, он совершенно излишен.

Мне сильно резануло слух. Такое бывает? 
Если я неправ, то как такое понимать, для меня это едва ли не оксюморон.

Если выражение легитимно, прошу объяснить, как его надо понимать.

Comment: Думаю, что у Вас сформировалось какое-то особое мнение о значении в русском языке слова "пафос". Посмею предложить толкования разных авторов http://tolkslovar.ru/p1992.html

Comment: Если бы у меня одного, не стал бы и спрашивать.  
Я исхожу из Кузнецова, или если угодно - из приведенного Софией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно говорить  с искренним воодушевлением или с искренней страстью, но искренний пафос – это, действительно, оксюморон, фигура речи, которая должна ясно осознаваться как сочетание противоположных слов. А если это не стилистическая фигура, то это стилистическая ошибка, так как эти слова не могут раскрывать общую тему.

Искренний - простосердечный, открытый, прямой, честной, душевный, непритворный,  а пафос -   это не только воодушевление и страсть, но еще и чрезмерная приподнятость тона речи, подъём, рассчитанный  на публику  - поэтому так часто говорится  о ложном, фальшивом, неискреннем пафосе.

Значение слова «пафосный» чаще негативное и по отношению к «искреннему»  прямо противоположное, например: «Чего я в тебе, Немчинов, не люблю: пафосный ты человек». Также:  пафосный, идейно озабоченный, канонический герой; пустой  и театрально пафосный текст;  пафосный и фальшиво негодующий тон.

Поэтому выражение "искренний пафос" в стихотворном тексте может иметь иронический смысл.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1

Также обратим внимание на синонимичные ряды слов и однородность с такими прилагательными. Мы часто говорим: пафосный, лицемерный, фальшивый, но не можем сказать: пафосный, искренний. И никакие словарные определения не могут изменить эту ситуацию.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2

Остается обратиться к реальным текстам и определить их стилистику (например, прямой или иронический смысл):

(1) Одни это делают с завистью, другие ― с искренним пафосом бедных, но гордых регионалов [Юрий Чувашев. Такая разная Москва (2002).

(2) Они заливались вдохновенно и отовсюду, некоторые с искренним пафосом. (Василий Белов. Плотницкие рассказы).

(3) Итак, кадеты, эсеры, официальные меньшевики ― одни за страх, другие за совесть, одни с искренним пафосом, другие с кисло-пренебрежительной улыбкой ―принесли к колыбели коалиции свое «доверие и поддержку». [Н. Н. Суханов. Записки о революции / Книга 4 (1918-1921)].

Мне кажется, что во всех случаях "искренний пафос" - это оформление вынужденной позиции,  то есть люди пытаются убедить сами себя, что думают и действуют искренне, а не по необходимости. При этом автор сомневается в такой искренности.

Comment: Не согласен. Пафос — это, по сути, явная эмоциональная подача, которое может быть как искренним, так и наигранным, потому оксюморона тут нет.

Comment: Вот предложение: "Как отличить пафос от искренних чувств?" Здесь, как и во многих других ситуациях, пафос и искренность - это противоположности. Когда слышишь пафосную речь, трудно быть уверенным в ее искренности. А вдруг это только имитация истинных чувств, ведь пафосные люди очень любят казаться искренними? (Правда, есть пафос в искусстве и литературе, но это уже термин, совсем другое содержание,например: "Пафос Делакруа - искренний, не наигранный пафос"). Искренний пафос и пафосная искренность - в обычной  жизни такими выражениями следует пользоваться осторожно.

Comment: Мне кажется это противопоставление натянутым, ведь пафос и искренность являются понятиями разных плоскостей. Антонимом к "патетичный" будет "хладнокровный", "невозмутимый" или что-то вроде того. К слову, "вкрадчивый", которое по уровню эмоциональности прямо противоположно "патетичному", как раз имеет оттенок фальшивости, лести.

Comment: У слова ПАФОСНЫЙ сегодня 3 значения:1)торжественный, приподнятый, восторженный, воодушевлённый.2)лицемерный, слащавый, фальшивый, театральный.3)престижный.( Пафосный  рассказ.- с пафосом героизма, например)2) Автор и сыграл на самых низменных пафосно-сентиментальных чувствах. 3)  Пафосный игровой ноутбук. 
Категория пафос изначально предполагала вызывать у читателя высокие чувства, благородные мысли, воодушевление, духовный подъем,а теперь вот приобрела негативный оттенок.Будем надеяться, что не все ещё забыли классический смысл слова.

Comment: >У слова ПАФОСНЫЙ сегодня 3 значения: 1) торжественный, приподнятый, восторженный, воодушевлённый;  
  
Если ограничиться этим значением, сем искренний пафос (коль скоро вы предполагаете существование такового) отличается от неискреннего?

Comment: @София, пожалуй, я в основном соглашусь. Уже потому, что я, еще не читая вашего текста, мысленно оперировал в рассуждениях примерно теми же терминами - от оксюморона до синонимического ряда.
Ну ладно, спасибо, я еще подумаю.  
(+)  
И все-таки, даже если принять, что сочетаемость тут не нарушена, это как-то по-другому должно называться. "убежденная напыщенность"? Вот уж где оксюморон-то.

Comment: "С искренним пафосом" — это "с неподдельной страстью", "с наивной пылкостью (присущей молодым людям)" или что-то вроде того.

Comment: >"С искренним пафосом" — это "с неподдельной страстью", "с наивной пылкостью (присущей молодым людям)" или что-то вроде того.  
  
А вот тут не согласен категорически. Пафос - это что-то торжественное, вощвышенное, помпезное, чопорное даже. Без этого никак. А пылкость и страсть - какая уж тут торжественность. Это суетность чувств.

Comment: Старшее значение слова "пафос" — это именно что "страсть", говорить патетично — это говорить с жаром, со страстью, которые часто и способствуют появлению оттенка торжественности. "Клянусь Богом, я не оставлю тебя, даже если это погубит всё, что я сделал, и цена самой жизни меркнет перед тобой, — прошептал Рикардо" — это пафос. Есть ли тут страсть, пылкость? Мне кажется, их наличие очевидно. Страсть, пыл, жар — это душевное состояние "неравновесия", взвинченность, эмоционального подъёма.

Comment: Страсть и пылкость имеются, но для пафосности требуется еще публичность. Пафосная речь предназначена  для аудитории, которая может быть различной (в крайнем случае аудитория состоит из одного говорящего). И говорящий всегда видит себя и сцену со стороны, при этом всегда оценивая свою речь и ее воздействие на слушателей (хотя бы интуитивно). Здесь и проходит граница: можно говорить пылко, страстно, искренне и  при этом высказывать свои истинные чувства, но это не пафос. Пафос - это прием, а это уже не искренность.

Answer (score 3):

А
 почему возвышенный стиль и воодушевление не могут по-вашему быть 
искренними? Нередко видел, как человек глубокоубежденный в своем мнении,
 сам того не замечая, переходил на пафосную риторику, будучи при этом 
абсолютно искренним. Хотя согласен, что ситуации, где пафос лишь 
скрывает отсутствие чувств встречаются в нашей жизни на порядок чаще.

Comment: Хотел было сразу плюсануть, но быстро понял, что вы только еще больше запутали. Если принять "пасофный" модет быть еще и бессознательным ("сам того не замечая"), то это туши свет.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, литературным вариантом является "патетичный", а не "пафосный". Что касается "как это понимать", то немного неясно определение: "искренний, пафосный" (перечисление вариантов) или "искренний И пафосный" (одновременно)?

Я бы трактовал их так.
 1) Искренний, пафосный. Наполненный чувством, неприкрытым переживанием.
 2) Искренний и пафосный. То есть, с одной стороны, честный, а с другой – с явными воодушевлением, страстью. Страсть можно и "симулировать", потому уточняется, что она искренняя, а правду можно говорить и хладнокровно, например.

P.S. Не согласен, что пафос является только приёмом и потому не может быть искренним. Если человек говорит торжественно, пылко, то это лишь передаёт силу и качество эмоций, но не говорит об их искренности или против неё. У меня нет таких ассоциаций в отношении "патетичный", как "фальшивый", "лицемерный".

Comment: Почему же? А лирический пафос?

Comment: Что "лирический пафос"? Не очень понимаю вопрос.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, литературным вариантом является "патетичный", а не "пафосный".  Я ответил: " А лирический пафос?" , т.е. в литературе пафос есть, как художественный прием.

Comment: Смысл в образовании прилагательного: пафос -> патетический (от греч. "патетик").

Answer (score 1):

Разве что в литературе, как стилистический прием.

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю предыдущих собеседников. Если речь идёт о произведении или публицистическом выступлении, это пафос в риторике.
Пафос используется для выражения сильных возвышенных эмоций, воодушевления, страсти, душевного надрыва. Это сильный прием, который нередко призван для формирования сочувствия к героям литературного произведения, сопереживания им и их действиям.

Литературоведы различают следующие виды пафоса в произведениях поэтов и писателей: героический пафос, драматический, романтический, сентиментальный, гуманистический и лирический.

Основная задача лирического пафоса – найти эмоциональный отклик у читателя, заставить его сопереживать героям. Искренний лирический пафос создает необходимые автору чувства, подкрепляя изложенные в нем мысли.

Я с искренним пафосом тратила душу

На сказки для взрослых. Они не сбывались.

Я молча кричала "Послушай!Послушай!",

Но Вы уходили. Мы просто прощались.

Есть наигранный пафос, а есть искренний. Высокие чувства никто не отменял, а о них можно говорить тихо, спокойно, а можно с пафосом (о любви к отечеству), но без показного патриотизма, без призывов и патетических жестов - искренне, так что вполне легитимная фраза.

Comment: Спасибо. Не погу пока до конца прочувствовать Вашу точку зрения. По частям понимаю и даже в чем-то согласен - вместе картина не скаладывается.

>Я с искренним пафосом тратила душу  
  
Воспринимаю как поэтическую фигуру речи. Оксюморон или что-то подобное. Здесь "искренний пафос" - одержимость. Если я не прав, хотелось бы узнать Ваше понимание, лучше всего - синонимичным рядом.    
  
А если прав (и насчет оксюморона, и насчет одержимости), то единственное ли это понимание "искреннего пафоса" - или оно здесь окказионально?

Comment: Поэтическая фигура здесь "тратила душу"-метафора и "искренний"-эпитет, но не оксюморон. Первоначальное значение слова - страсть (греч.), а страсть бывает разная: любовь к отечеству имеет положительную окрашенность, любовь к деньгам,вину,скупость(это тоже страсть), к себе любимому и только - отрицательную. Вот у Ефремовой-http://slovonline.ru/slovar_efremova/b-16/id-66816/pafos.html А вот употребление в прессе : http://www.diclib.com/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%81/show/ru/examples_ru/%D0%9F/7523/540/0/10/39279#.VCpWwqDA0hY

Comment: Синонимы слова пафос - горячность; воодушевление, жар, подъем, пылкость, патетика, возбуждение, пыл,  энтузиазм, вдохновение, приподнятость, живинка, страсть, эмоция, экстаз.И только последнее вызывает чувство неискренности.Ко всем остальным подходит эпитет ИСКРЕННИЙ. Призывы бить фашистов были все пафосные, но они искренни и вызывали положительные эмоции.Никак не оксюморон фраза:"Его речь наполнена искренним пафосом борьбы за Родину" - да, с жаром, с воодушевлением, с патетикой, но искренне, от души, не лицемеря.С искренним пафосом тратила душу - сильно чувствовала.

Comment: Вот Маяковский говорил пафосно(о своей огромной любовищи и о маленьких любятах), но его ТОГДА  понимали, он говорил искренне, правда, сейчас всё перевернулось, его обвиняют во всех грехах, только в одном обвинить не могут - в неискренности и наигранном пафосе.А я вот искренне восторгалась силой строк:"Читайте, завидуйте: Я гражданин Советского Союза". Пафосно, и ещё как! Но искренне!

Comment: Отрицательный смысл появился в эпоху застоя, там всё было пафосно=наигранно: всех любили, целовали, как Брежнев, едва не сплёвывая,театрально.Самое пафосное слово патриотизм потеряло искренний смысл. Это мы испортили смысл слова своими неискренними действиями.Начнём говорить искренне - то, что чувствуем на самом деле, появится вновь значение "жар любви к отечеству".И ничего отрицательного, напыщенного в нём не будет.

Comment: Пафос - это риторическая категория в литературе, которую разработал еще Аристотель. Она предназначена для передачи возвышенных эмоций, с надрывом, страстных и воодушевленных. Пафос бывает романтический, героический, драматический, сентиментальный и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, эти понятия не взаимоисключают одно другое. В русской культуре, конечно, принято ценить безыскусность, неподдельность, естественность (читай: «как в жизни») эмоции. Но пафос в «нелитературоведческом» смысле можно описать и как ощущение особости ситуации, того, что она не бытовая и не похожа на обычную жизнь и её прозу. Тогда при описании этой ситуации (будь то подвиг трехсот спартанцев при Фермопилах, сонеты Петрарки или переживания Чайльд-Гарольда) вполне можно ожидать, с одной стороны, пафоса и отхода от бытовой лексики, а с другой стороны — искренних увлечённости и переживания в связи с этими сюжетами.

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки нужен контекст. Потому что у слова "пафос" сейчас едва ли не основное значение – это "понты". А потом уже всякие там воодушевления.

Comment: Возьмите тот контекст, который вам нужен. 
Вопрос заключался не расшифровке смысла сказанного (разговор и без того велся на повышенных тонах), а, говоря просто, в понимании того, почему мне это слух резануло.